# Load multiple certificates into PKCS12 with openssl

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, pkcs#12

I am trying to load multiple certificates using openssl into the PKCS12 format. The command is as follows:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert1.arm -inkey cert1_private_key.pem -certfile cert2.arm -certfile cert3.arm -certfile RootCert.pem -name "Test" -out test.p12
```

Having parsed the generated PKCS12 file, only the last certificate has been included into the file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -info -nodes
```

I also tried to import them separately into the pkcs12 file while in all the attempts, only the last certificate was remained in the file.

Any idea where is the problem to solve it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, make sure all your certificates are in PEM format.  Then, make a SINGLE file called "certs.pem" containing the rest of the certificates (cert2.arm, cert3.arm, and RootCert.pem).

Then use the command like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert1.arm -inkey cert1_private_key.pem -certfile certs.pem -name "Test" -out test.p12
```

The [openssl pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/pkcs12.html) documentation explains the different options.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it automatically? Manually adding the certificates into a single file doesn't seem practical (when it comes to add/remove cert from PKCS12 file).

Comment: You could concatenate the individual files into a combined file on the same command line that you use to create the pkcs12 file.  For example in Windows, `type cert2.arm cert3.arm RootCert.pem > combined.pem & openssl pkcs12 ...`.  In Linux/Unix, you could do `cat cert2.arm cert3.arm RootCert.pem > combined.pem; openssl pkcs12 ...`

Comment: Is there any way, using `openssl`, to *add* a certificate to an existing `pkcs12` file? I know you can assemble one from scratch, but what about just adding one?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I am struggling with this also. I believe only keytool from Java can handle this properly.

Comment: I think it's a limitation in openssl tool. I always have to append all certificates I want in a PEM file and then use openssl to export that to pkcs12 format