# openssl .p12 cert only has one of the concatenated .pem cert info

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, pem, p12

I have two .p12 certs that I converted into .pem files using this command:

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert1.p12 -out cert1.pem -nodes`

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert2.p12 -out cert2.pem -nodes`

Then I catenated the two .pem files into one .pem file:

`cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > combo.pem`

Then I converted the `combo.pem` into a .p12 cert:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in combo.pem -out combo.p12`

But when I went to check the contents of the `combo.p12` cert, it only had the information for cert1.pem:

`keytool -v -list -keystore combo.p12`

I want the `combo.p12` cert to have both .pem cert information. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like your question is a duplicate of this one: [Load multiple certificates into PKCS12 with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19704950/1380680). Are you trying to put a certificate with its key as well as its chain of trust into the `.p12` bundle?

Comment: I saw that question but I think I have a slightly different situation because I don't have an `-in` or `-inkey` private cert for both .p12 certs. But to answer your question, yes I am trying to do that..

Answer (score 0):

For illustration purposes, let's take a look what happens when repeating your experiment using the StackExchange.com certificate chain. I have downloaded them from the website and converted them to PEM and concatenated them into a single PEM file, the same way you did. It is called `SE.pem`. Then converting them into `PKCS#12` format like this yields:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in SE.pem -out SE.p12
unable to load private key
140736004633472:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:686:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

You did not mention this. The additional parameter needed to work without private keys is `-nokeys`, like this:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in SE.pem -out SE.p12 -nokeys
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

Then verifying that the resulting `.p12` file has everything in it:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -in SE.p12 | grep subject=
Enter Import Password:
MAC:sha1 Iteration 2048
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
subject=/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/O=Stack Exchange, Inc./CN=*.stackexchange.com
subject=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
subject=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
```

I have not been able to figure out why `keytool` does not list the certificates properly, the two tools seems to expect different contents for the `.p12` bundle:

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore SE.p12 -storetype pkcs12
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

I might actually ask a different SO question about that myself :-). Is that essential for your situation, or just another verification step?

Comment: Keystore probably does not recognize the entries because of missing special attributes as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959499/5302210) by user [Bragolgirith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620458/bragolgirith).